# Netbeans using cache instead of opening project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans version 15 and JDK 11.

When I want to open a class referenced in a project that belong to another project, by Ctrl + click on that class Name, Netbeans open a read only version of this class, that appears to be located in Netbeans cache in:
*C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\15\packageName\myProject.jar*

The project of the class I want to open is in my project list and in my .m2 repository, and I built it (clean and build).

Why can't Netbeans open the class from my sources? Is there a configuration setting that I have missed?

This worked perfectly with my previous version of Netbeans (12) on a laptop.

What I have already tried: Clean and build the project of the class that I want to open.

Comment: I'm using jdk 11 for the build.

Comment: That's what I answer to stackoverflow when he ask me the things I try to solve the problem, I'll edit to make it more readable.